# Gnome music pop-up window on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, music, ubuntu-unity

I recently installed [Gnome music](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Music) on a Ubuntu 14.04 system  with Unity desktop. However, there is a peculiar issue. Every time I play a song several windows pop up (six same windows for each song). So when the entire song list is played I have several pop-up windows open and I have to manually close them. Is there a setting which can help resolve this situation? Is it particular to Unity desktop?

See attached pic. 
[image: Gnome music pop-up window]

Comment: I can confirm this on a few installs of 16.04. To test I used a 16.04 VM installed `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` logged into the gnome session and gnome-music worked as intended. Back in the unity session I got the pop in the screenshot (and the unity desktop has gnome elements all over the place and looks broken).